# VisualStudio 2015 linker looking for VS 2010 library

Tags: c++, boost-python, programmers-notepad

I am trying to compile a old VS2010 project in VS2015 with boost.python 1_67_0 from 1_53 and python 35.

Getting it compile was not too hard, just a few tweaks to include path and updating a couple of python 2 string handling to python 3.

But I am stuck on linking because the linker fails at:

`LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_python-vc100-mt-gd-1_67.lib'`

Which really does not make sense because the library version should be vc140. In the library path there does exist libboost_python35-vc140-mt-gd-x32-1_67.lib and a few others libboost_python35-vc140* options.

Where is it getting the name 'boost_python-vc100-mt-gd-1_67.lib' from? (i.e. is this something I missed in the configuration?)

Comment: Boost can figure out what libraries need to be linked when you build it.  So basic diagnostic here is that you did not rebuild boost.  Who does, nobody enjoys chewing tin-foil.  Consider passing to job to [somebody else](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/).

Comment: So by going to "Property manager" and looking at the project properties > Linker > All Options and found the library.

But now I have `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_pythonPY_MAJOR_VERSIONPY_MINOR_VERSION-vc140-mt-gd-x32-1_67.lib'` which I bet is happening because the PY_MAJOR_VERSION and PY_MINOR_VERSION are not defined somewhere...

Comment: I only have boost 1_67 and it was just downloaded and built and all of the libraries are there. It was not boost but just some project property plugged in to the configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Visual Studio Boost uses boost/configure/auto_link.hpp to generate the library names and add them to the linker's dependencies. One of the arguments to this bit of code is BOOST_LIB_NAME which for boost::python is defined in boost/python/detail/config.hpp. In version 1_67_0 this is currently:

`#define BOOST_LIB_NAME boost_python##PY_MAJOR_VERSION##PY_MINOR_VERSION`

Where the python patchlevel.h has the definitions for PY_MAJOR_VERSION and PY_MINOR_VERSION.

This means that the library name itself does not need to explicitly added to the your Visual Studio project. Just the path to the boost libraries directory.

For me I needed to remove any (boost) library names from:

- Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies
- Configuration Properties > Linker > All Options > Additional Dependencies

And needed to ensure that I built boost::python with the shared (dll) libraries since I would building a DLL. The static libraries are libboost*.lib and the shared libraries are boost*.lib. To force the generation of the shared libraries I used:

`C:\dev\boost\boost_1_67_0> b2.exe link=shared,static --with-python -a`